# output cache execution leads to object reference exception in session. How To Solve that?

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Im Working in mvc C# project now. i just want to take some values from output cache. because it will reduce round robin in DB.
So i Used *[OutputCache(Duration = 1800,VaryByParam = "none")]*

when the action method is hitted for the first time, its getting the list values correctly,
Acually i assigned *Duration*  for 30mins. So next request for that Action Method should not strike my DB, it has to give the cached Result.

*BUt* it lead to an exception, showing "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", which is from the Session

My Code is:

** This is Controller Action **

```
    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(Duration = 1800, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public JsonResult GetStateList()
    {
        Result objResult = new Result();

       VRecruitService.StateClient objState = new VRecruitService.StateClient();
        using (CandidateModel objModel = new CandidateModel())
        {
            objResult.Data = objModel.GetStateList().Data;
        }
        return Json(objResult);
    }
```

and ** This is model Class code, where im getting that exception **

```
     public static Employee User
     {
        get
        {
            object objUser = HttpContext.Current.Session["userDetails"]; 

            // In this above Session only im getting that Exception.

            if (objUser is VRecruitService.Employee)
                return (VRecruitService.Employee)objUser;
            else
                return null;
        }
        set 
        { 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["userDetails"] = value; 
        }
     }
```

Please give me Solution. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to format your question correclty : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ** Yeah Sure** @Joseph

Answer (score 0):

I believe that since you are caching the output, you need to decorate the controller class with

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
```

so that session state is available. Also it seems that an HttpGet verb may make more sense given that you are not POST'ing data to the action.